# How to get the max and min values of a number

Tags: java

I tried to make a program that gets the max and min value of the numbers in which the user entered.

Here is the code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int value;
boolean isInt;
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
isInt = in.hasNextInt();
if (isInt == true){
value = in.nextInt();
}
for (int i = 0; isInt == true; i = i){
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    isInt = in.hasNextInt();
    if (isInt == true){
        value = in.nextInt();
    }
}
System.out.println(min);
System.out.println(max);
```

And the output is:
   2147483647
  -2147483648

What is the error in the code?

Comment: Pseudocode? Is this not your real code?

Comment: This program doesn't make sense on many different levels. It seems like you need a Java tutorial.

Comment: What do you think `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` represent?

Comment: What you probably want to do is to have an arraylist of integers and store every integer there. When the user is done with his input, search through the list and find the smallest and largest value and print them. What you have done here is far from achieving what you want.

Comment: @Gendarme. You don't need to store all the numbers to do that. You just need to store the latest min and max, as OP has show intention to do. I do agree with you that this is very far from achieving what OP wants though.

Comment: Yeah, good point.

Answer (score 4):

The definition for Min and Max of integer is not to get the Min and MAX from input.

They are constant value.

MAX_VALUE
A constant holding the maximum value an int can have, 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

MIN_VALUE
A constant holding the minimum value an int can have, -2<sup>31</sup>.

Comment: Sorry I clobbered your edit. I will revert if you prefer.

Comment: No problem, I am sure these two numbers can not be changed.

Comment: I hope not, although eventually they may go up to -2^64 and 2^64-1.

Comment: Agree with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Once you initialize them, you never change `max` or `min` anywhere.

Comment: Ok, i don't change it but why it the output is:                                         2147483647
-2147483648

Comment: @TheWarior. Because those are the values of Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE expressed in decimal notation.

Comment: I want the max to be the greatest number the user entered.And the min to be the smallest number the user entered.

Comment: @TheWarior. Yeah, we go that. What are you planning on actually doing to get that?

Answer (score 2):

First thing: what you have is not pseudo code. It's just bad actual code.

To answer your immediate question, you need to set the values of `min` and `max` to something other than their initial values. They will not magically update themselves.

There are a couple of additional things you are doing that should probably be fixed:

- Since `isInt` is `boolean`, you do not need to compare it to `true` to get its `boolean` value: `if(isInt)` is fine.
- Every time you call `nextInt()` on the `Scanner`, you invalidate the previous result of `hasNextInt()`. In other words, once you get the next int, you don't know that there is going to be another one in the input until you call `hasNextInt()` again. Your `for` loop makes this assumption.

Here is a version of the code that not only fixes the three issues noted above, but is also indened correctly:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int value;
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
while(in.hasNextInt())
{
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    value = in.nextInt();
    if(value < min)
    {
        min = value;
    }
    if(value > max)
    {
        max = value;
    }
}
System.out.println(min);
System.out.println(max);
```

Note that I do not use an `else` clause when comparing `value` against the current `min` and `max`. This will ensure that `min` and `max` are correctly set to the first input even if there is only one number in the sequence.

Comment: Sorry for that bad question your answer is right but you forgot to add the prompt System.out.print("Enter an integer: "); before the loop

Comment: I see. Fixed. `hasNextInt()` is the one that actually does the input...

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your code are you changing the values of max or min. If you want to print the min and max of the inputted numbers you could run a couple comparisons for maximum and minimum. The easiest way would look like this, inserted after you take in the value for the integer:

```
if(value > max)
    max = value;
if(value < min)
    min = value;
```

You should probably remove these lines as well as they're no longer needed:

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
isInt = in.hasNextInt();
if (isInt == true)
{
value = in.nextInt();
}
```

Additionally both isInt and value will have to be initialized to a value.

Comment: You forgot the incorrect use of `Scanner.hasNextInt()`

Comment: Also, your last statement is untrue/superfluous. They are being initialized, just not in the line that declares them, and that's fine since it's done before they get read out.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks, didn't notice that. Your answer is much more through than mine anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much posted it just to get points. I think the other two answers are actually what OP needs (a metaphorical beating to make them sit down and RTFM instead of wasting our time).